# Checking if a Map contains a key of class type in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, contains

I'm new to Scala, and there's something I'm having trouble figuring out.
I have the following method:

```
def updateSongCount(song : Song) {
   if(this.listeningCountMap.contains(song)) {
     this.listeningCountMap(song) += 1
   } 
   else 
   {
     this.listeningCountMap += (song -> 1)
   }
  }
```

listeningCountMap is defined like this:

```
var listeningCountMap = Map[Song, Int]()
```

Now, the thing is Song is a class type and it has several parameters (like title, singer, etc).
When I do the contains, even if all the parameters are the same between the two songs - it adds them as two seperate entries.
I'm coming from C# and I'm used to having to override GetHashCode and Equals in order for contains to understand when two instances of my class are considered equal, and I suppose what I'm missing is the equivalent for that in scala. Could you please tell me how do we do that in Scala?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `Song` is defined as `case class` then equals and hashCode method is generated by the compiler using primary constructor parameters:

```scala
case class Song(id: Int, title: String)
```

In this example equals and hashCode considers both `id` and `title` fields.

In case you don't need using all fields for comparison you can just override equals/hashCode methods:

```scala
case class Song(id: Int, title: String) {
  override def hashCode() = title.hashCode()

  override def equals(obj: Any) = title.equals(if (obj != null) obj.asInstanceOf[Song].title else null)
}
```

Comment: Cool, I understand and it worked, thanks a lot! But what if I wanted to define something in the middle - like let's say I want to compare it by only one or two parameters - let's say compare only by the field title - how would I do that?

Comment: @Shirli having a case class with a custom `equals` & `hashCode` is a bad practice, you may break that down to two different case classes where one contains the other. Also, you should stay away from mutability while learning the language, and you may want to give it a look at the **Scaladoc** to find helper methods like `Map.empty` and `map.updatedWith` which can help you reduce the boilerplate and be more declarative. - Anyways, feel free to drop by the official [**Discord** server](https://discord.gg/9nPaEYgp) if you want to follow up with more questions.

Comment: BTW, Bondarenko, your answer is wrong. `equals` is not returning a boolean and you are missing `canEquals` which can result in some weird bugs. This is the main reason for not defining those methods ourselves, they are tricky to get right.

Comment: if you `case class Song(title: String)(id: Int)` then you don't need to override `equals` and `hashCode` like that.

Comment: Thank you all very much! 
@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I'll look into the platforms you've recommended. I guess I'm lacking some basic differences between what I'm used to and what Scala is actually used for, so I'll try to learn that first..